# Redis healthcheck not working with spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to do request on `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` to check if everything is UP.

When communication is between locally run JAVAAPP -> REDIS in docker container the status is UP.

But when communication is between dockereized JAVAAPP -> REDIS in docker container the status is DOWN

```
"redis": {
        "status": "DOWN",
        "details": {
            "error": "org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis"
        }
    }
```

application.properties has :

```
spring.redis.host=redis
spring.redis.port=6379
```

docker-compose:

```
    version: "3.9"
services:
    JAVAPP:
    container_name: JAVAPP
    image: JAVAPP:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:6.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

I tried do add env variables in dockerfile and in docker-compose.

Do you have any ideas why is it working locally but not between containers?